# Why iam not getting this number as integer in php

Tags: php, html, css, logic

I am trying to print table only if user enters integer value( `no` string, float etc) but this code is not working let me now what i am missing to get only integer values without using `JAVASCRIPT` at front end. Let me know if im missing some logic.

This is my php code (**index.php**) --

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>table Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<table width="29%" border="1">
<form name="mytableform" id="mytableform" action="mytabledata.php" method="POST">
  <tr>
    <td width="42%">Enter any munber :&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="58%"><input type="text" name="mynumber" id="mynumber" />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter limit :&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="limit" type="text" id="limit" />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
 </form> 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

My **mytabledata.php** content file --

```
<?php

$number = $_POST['mynumber'];
$limit = $_POST['limit'];

//var_dump($number);
//var_dump($limit);

if( is_int($number) )
{
    for($i=1;$i<=$limit;$i++)
    {
    $p= $number * $i;
    echo $number." X ".$i." = "." ".$p.";";
    echo "<br />";
    }
}
else{
echo "Please check the type of data you are entering.";
}
```

Comment: why dont you cast given number to int? like `$number=(int)$_POST["mynumber"]` ?

Comment: @Sabin if i have to typecast then its of no use to have is_int in my code..

Comment: @user1594368, then use is_numeric function to check instead of is_int

Comment: @BhuvanRikka if you type 25 or any number then this code is going to print the table ..but its not..at least have a look at the code to grab the logic instead of just emphasizing on sentences

Comment: @Sabin even this is not going to work bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value from your `POST` is type of string. To use it you can do this:

```
$number = intval( $_POST['mynumber'] );
```

Comment: If you want to do more than just sanitize the input you should really use [`filter_var`](http://tw2.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) as suggested by complex857. There's [an example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php#91681) of how to set the `min_range` and `max_range` options in the comments section.

Comment: Sidenote: using `(int)$_POST['mynumber']` is much faster than `intval($_POST['mynumber'])`, if anyone cares for performance.

Answer (score 3):

Input coming from HTTP (`$_POST`, `$_GET`, etc.) will always be `string`type in php land.
If you want to validate if that string can be interpreted as number you can use `is_numeric` or the [Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) library.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$_POST` values are always submitted as ASCII text (i.e. they are strings). Use the [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function to convert the strings to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Values of `$_POST` are always strings, there is no automatic conversion to numbers.

What you want to use in your script is probably not `is_int()`, which checks for variable type, but `is_numeric()` which checks if a variable contains a numeric value (be it int or string).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the below mentioned condition, when i have to check for integer type

```
if(is_numeric($val) && intval($val)==$val) {
/*Place your code here*/
}
```

Comment: This is a very good code..will surely up vote it once i will gain 15 points :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `is_numeric` instead of `is_int`.
The answers mentioned above is good as well, but is_numeric is better since it returns true or false right away.

```
 if( is_numeric($number) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(((int) $number) == $number)
{
    echo "is integer";
}
```

Edit: Or you can use regex for this like this

```
if(preg_match("/^\d+$/", $number))
{
    echo "is integer";
}
```